# Java server - multiple clients handling - is using threads optimal?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, client-server

I am developing server-client communication based system and I am trying to determine the most optimal way to handle multiple clients. What is important I really **don't want to use any third-party libraries**.

In many places in the Internet I saw this resolved by creating a separate thread for each connections, but I don't think it is the best way when I assume there will be a huge number of connections (maybe I'm wrong). So, solution that I'm thinking of is

**Creating queue of events** and handling them by workers - the defined pool of threads (where there is a constant number n of workers). This solution seems to be pretty slow, but I can not imagine how big difference will be in case of handling huge amount of clients.

I've been thinking also about load-balancing via multiinstantiatig the server (on different physical machines) but it is only a nice add-on to any solution, not the solution itself.

I am aware that Java is not really async-friendly, but maybe I lack some knowledge and there is nice solution. I'll be grateful for any sugestions.

Additional info:

1. I assume really big number of connections
2. Every connection will last for a long time (days, maybe weeks)
3. Program will need to send some data to specified client quite frequently
4. Each client will send data to server about once a 3 seconds

To avoid discussion (as SO is not a place for them):

1. One client - one thread
2. Many clients - constant number of threads and events pool
3. Any async-like solution, that I'm not aware of
4. Anything else?

Comment: Threads will probably work the best for what you have described. if your worried about optimization and resource usage then consider using c++\c which will allow the usage of async-sockets

Comment: C# also allows asynchronous communication.

Comment: @TheBetaProgrammer I didn't event think about using C++, no clue why, so thanks! Anyway, Java has many built-in features I really appreciate and it'd be great to keep them

Comment: @WilliamMorrison unfortunately, I am not familiar with C# that well. Also, as far as I know, it is strongly related to Windows, which I don't use, so I suppose there would occur many strange situations I'd have to handle. But thanks anyway, it's another thing that makes me closer to meet C#!

Comment: What is a _big_ number of connections (per host)? 100k? 1 million? 10 million?

Comment: @nosid thanks for noticing, could be misleading. About 300k maximum

Comment: I don't think you can even connect 300k clients to a single PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest starting off with the simple architecture of one thread per connection. Modern JVMs on sufficiently sized systems can support thousands of threads. You might be pleasantly surprised at how well even this simple scheme works. If you need 300k connections, though, I doubt that one thread per connection will work. (But I've been wrong before.) You might have to fiddle with the thread stack size and OS resource limits.

A queueing system will help decouple the connections from the threads handling the work, but it will add to the amount of work done per message received from each client. This will also add to latency (but I'm not sure how important that is). If you have 300k connections, you'll probably want to have a pool of threads reading from the connections, and you'll also want to have more than one queue through which the work flows. If you have 300k clients sending data once every 3 seconds, that's 100k ops/sec, which is a lot of data to shove through a single queue. That might turn into a bottleneck.

Another approach probably worth investigating is to have a pool of worker threads, but instead of each worker reading data from a queue written by connection reader threads, have each worker handle a bunch of sockets directly. Use a NIO `Selector` to have each thread wait on multiple sockets. Say, have 100 threads each handling 3,000 sockets. Or perhaps have 1,000 threads each handling 300 sockets. This depends on the amount of data and the amount of work necessary to process each incoming message. You'll have to experiment. This will probably be considerably simpler than using asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Thanks a lot, You've helped me to sort it out in my mind, so it's time  to try it and find best solution experimentally. Selector including option seems to be pretty good compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 has true asynchronous IO under the NIO package I've heard. I don't know much about it other than its difficult to work with.

Basic IO in java is blocking.  This means using a fixed number of threads to support many clients is likely not possible with basic IO as you could have all threads tied up in blocking calls reading from clients who aren't sending data.

I suggest you look in asynchronous IO with Grizzly/Netty, if you change your mind on 3rd party libraries.

If you haven't changed your mind, look into NIO yourself.